# Copy data from a on prem s3 object storage to another object storage using hadoop cli commands

Tags: amazon-s3, hadoop, hdfs

I'm trying to copy data from 1 s3 object storage to another object storage (both on prem) using hadoop cli.

Both storage have different endpoint, access keys and secret keys.

```
hdfs dfs -Dfs.s3a.endpoint=xxxx:xxxx -Dfs.s3a.access.key=xxxxx -Dfs.s3a.secret.key=xxxx -ls s3a://bucket-name/
```

this works for both storage.

But i'm not able to copy from 1 to another as i have no clue how to enter multiple values for access keys/secret keys/endpoints in a single command.

I can do this using a java code, but want to do it through commandline.

Thanks.

Comment: S3 cli itself should have tools to copy between buckets/regions/accounts. Why do you want to use hadoop cli?

Comment: We do not have s3 cli installed on our cluster, as from the beginnning we have using hdfs utils, have intergrated s3 creds for 1 object storage in core-site.xml.

Comment: What is the "other object store"? Is it S3? According to this answer, two account keys aren't possible, and you need a temporary destination (and create smaller data batches) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51153521/copying-s3-files-across-aws-account-using-s3-dist-cp#51162095

Comment: And if you're using Minio, as "on prem S3" that cli is easy to install, but it too has replication solutions available, so you shouldn't have to do batch copies

Comment: @OneCricketeer Thanks for the alternatives mate. Although i did find a solution. You can set per-bucket level details in the command.

 hdfs dfs -Dfs.s3a.multipart.purge=false -Dfs.s3a.bucket.bucket_name_1.endpoint=xxxx -Dfs.s3a.bucket.bucket_name_1.access.key=xxxx -Dfs.s3a.bucket.bucket_name_1.secret.key=xxxx -Dfs.s3a.bucket.bucket_name_2.endpoint=xxxx -Dfs.s3a.bucket.bucket_name_2.access.key=xxxx -Dfs.s3a.bucket.bucket_name_2.secret.key=xxxx -ls s3a://bucket_name_1/ s3a://bucket_name_2/ 

endpoint can have :port based on network configurations. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can set per-bucket level details in the command.

```
hdfs dfs \
-Dfs.s3a.multipart.purge=false \
-Dfs.s3a.bucket.bucket_name_1.endpoint=xxxx \
-Dfs.s3a.bucket.bucket_name_1.access.key=xxxx \
-Dfs.s3a.bucket.bucket_name_1.secret.key=xxxx \
-Dfs.s3a.bucket.bucket_name_2.endpoint=xxxx \
-Dfs.s3a.bucket.bucket_name_2.access.key=xxxx \
-Dfs.s3a.bucket.bucket_name_2.secret.key=xxxx \
-ls s3a://bucket_name_1/ s3a://bucket_name_2/
```

endpoint can have :port based on network configurations.